# k_th smallest element per group in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have a data table, `dt`, that looks like

```
   location year value
       NYC 2026     1
       NYC 2026     2
       NYC 2026     3
       NYC 2026     4
       NYC 2026     5
        LA 2026     6
        LA 2026     7
        LA 2026     8
        LA 2026     9
        LA 2026    10
```

I would like to group them by `city` and `year` and find the 2nd smallest element in
the column `value`, per each group, where the desired result looks like:

```
   location year value
        NYC  2026     2
         LA  2026     7
```

`dt %>% grou_by(location, year) %>% nth(value, 2)`

Would not work. Any help is appreciated.

The data table above can be created by:

```
dt <- structure(list(location = c("NYC", "NYC", "NYC","NYC", "NYC", 
                                   "LA", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LA"), 
                 year = c(2026, 2026, 2026, 2026, 2026,
                          2026, 2026, 2026, 2026, 2026),
                 value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
                           6, 7, 8, 9, 10)),
                 class = "data.table", 
                 row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(location) %>%
 arrange(value) %>%
 slice(2)
```

Here it groups by "location" column, arranges the values according "value" column and then keeps the second element.

```
  location  year value
  <chr>    <int> <int>
1 LA        2026     7
2 NYC       2026     2
```

Or if the values in "value" column could be duplicate, then you can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(location) %>%
 distinct(value, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
 arrange(value) %>%
 slice(2)
```

Or using `filter()` instead of `slice()`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(location) %>%
 arrange(value) %>%
 filter(row_number() == 2)
```

The same considering also possible duplicates:

```
df %>%
 group_by(location) %>%
 distinct(value, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
 arrange(value) %>%
 filter(row_number() == 2)
```

Or using `filter()` and `dense_rank()`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(location) %>%
 filter(dense_rank(value) == 2)
```

The same considering also possible duplicates:

```
df %>%
 group_by(location) %>%
 distinct(value, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
 filter(dense_rank(value) == 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `summarize` to work with `group_by`:

```
> dt %>% group_by(location, year) %>% arrange(value) %>%  summarize(value = nth(value, 2))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   location [2]
  location  year value
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 LA        2026     7
2 NYC       2026     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need the 2nd element, a partial sort shouldn't be out of the question.  I don't know if it is supported by `dplyr` or `data.table`, but it is with base R sorting (with restricted options), eg. something along the lines of

```
with(dt, lapply(split(dt, interaction(location, year)), 
  function(x) sort.int(x$value, partial=2)))
```

I doubt it would be faster than `dplyr` or `data.table` even if they are sorting fully given their optimizations, but maybe it would be worth looking into if efficiency is a concern.

Oh, you could also sort first, then group and simply select the nth value from each grouping saving the multiple sorting routines for each group.